# I am getting the following error TextView - findviewbyid kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mobile, kotlin-android-extensions

`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKZub.png)

the "- findViewById(R.id.signUpText)" getting error in android studio and the error message show
below

Error Message:

Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

can you guys help me to solve this error?`

Comment: Use `=` instead of `-`

Answer (score 0):

Change - to =

example

```
val tetxViewName:TextView=findViewById(R.id.textViewId)
```